# how can i get following-sibling using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

i have many tr tags in html code:

```
<div class="noticeTabBoxWrapper">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span>Text for anchor</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span>*constantly changing text*</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

In my code i write this:

```
//div[@class = 'noticeTabBoxWrapper']//span[contains(text(), 'Text for anchor')]").InnerText
```

How can I rewrite code so that I can extract the necessary text that follows immediately after the anchor?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `raw` is your sample data :

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);
var xpath = "//div[@class='noticeTabBoxWrapper']//span[contains(., 'Text for anchor')]/following::td[1]/span";
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(result.InnerText)
```

Output : `*constantly changing text*`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the tags. In my case the html code looks like this: <tr><td><span>Text for anchor</span></td><td><span>*constantly changing text*</span></span>/<td> Please tell me what the code will look like in this case? Thanks.

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer. `//div[@class='noticeTabBoxWrapper']//span[contains(., 'Text for anchor')]/../following-sibling::td/span` works too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Could you explain what means "/../" between code? Is this part of the syntax?

Comment: It is. ".." means "select the parent element". In this case, select the parent of the `span[contains(., 'Text for anchor')]` element. Feel free to mark your question as answered.